# Help in factorization (Explain if I was wrong)

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

> **Task:** Factorize $ax^2-a-x^2+x$.

And my answer is:

$$ a(x^2-1)-x(x-1)=a(x-1)(x+1)-x(x-1)$$

Am I right? If not, explain why and give the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, not correct.
I could be downvoted

$$ax^2-a-x^2+x=$$
$$a(x^2-1)-(x^2-x)=$$
$$a(x+1)\color{red}{(x-1)}-x\color{red}{(x-1)}=$$

$$\color{red}{(x-1)}\Bigl(a(x+1)-x\Bigr)$$

Comment: why do you always say you are going to be downvoted

Comment: @DerekLuna Because everyday i loose 30, 40 or 50 points without Any Reason.

Answer (score 0):

"Factoring" usually means to write the whole expression as a product, not just factoring some terms.

Can see that $(x-1)$ can be factored out of your last answer now?